# How do I hide the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, scrollview

While foucusing edittext, I would like to hide the soft keyboard when tapping outside the range.

MainActivity.kt

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                // container is ConstraintLayout
                binding.container.windowToken,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
            )
        }
        return false
    }
```

Input Method Manager is written in MainActivity

in a xml

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

When I create this layout, the keyboard does not hide when I tap outside the range
How can I hide the keyboard?

If I write only ConstraintLayout it works but no scrolling

xxFragment.kt

```
scrollView.setOnClickListener {
    val imm = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.scrollView.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
}
```

I tried the above code and it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `dispatchTouchEvent()` method of Activity.

Just write this code in your activity and it will hide soft keyboard as soon as you touch outside `EditText`. No need to call any function anywhere. `It will work on all the fragments of the activity`.

```
/**
 * Hide Keyboard when tapped outside editText
 */
private var pressTime: Long = 0L
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    val ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    ev?.let { event ->
        if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            val releaseTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (releaseTime - pressTime < 100) {
                currentFocus?.let { view ->
                    if (view is EditText) {
                        val touchCoordinates = IntArray(2)
                        view.getLocationOnScreen(touchCoordinates)
                        val x: Float = event.rawX + view.getLeft() - touchCoordinates[0]
                        val y: Float = event.rawY + view.getTop() - touchCoordinates[1]
                        //If the touch position is outside the EditText then we hide the keyboard
                        if (x < view.getLeft() || x >= view.getRight() || y < view.getTop() || y > view.getBottom()) {
                            val imm =
                                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
                            view.clearFocus()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign **id** to `ConstraintLayout`,

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android="@+id/cl_container" >
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

For your click listener,

```
binding.clContainer.setOnClickListener{
     val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
     inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```